# center content inside centered div

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<div class='container-main'>
 <div class='container-inner'>
  <div class='clickable-box'>
   stuff
  </div>
  <div class='clickable-box'>
   stuff
  </div>
  <div class='clickable-box'>
   stuff
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

.container-main {
 width: 100%;
}
.container-inner {
 width: 90%;
}
.clickable-box {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 /* ???? */
}
```

I'm trying to make it so the clickable box will be centered inside the inner container IF there isn't enough room for another clickable box next to it.

BUT if there is enough width (600px +) then they create 2 columns (which are together centered inside the inner container), and if theres more room even (900px +) then 3 columns etc...

in other words, when I start out with a window of width 500px, it should show 1 column of boxes all lined up under each other. As I drag the window out, the box should stay in the center until theres enough room for another to go next to it, and they create 2 columns instead, and so on.

But I don't want the column to float left or right while I'm dragging the window and leave a big empty space

Comment: are you talking about 600px + width or height??

Comment: width sorry! I'll change it in question

Comment: You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
.container-main {
 width: 100%;
}
.container-inner {
 width: 99%;
    text-align:center
}
.clickable-box {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 32%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is to set `clickable-box` to `display: inline-block`. Setting `display: inline-block` essentially makes the div act like text in regards to text-align rules, but still keeps some block properties as well. It's pretty sweet.

**HTML**

```
<div class='container-main'>
  <div class='container-inner'>
    <div class='clickable-box'>
     stuff
    </div>
    <div class='clickable-box'>
     stuff
    </div>
    <div class='clickable-box'>
     stuff
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container-main {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-inner {
  width: 90%;
}

.clickable-box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPOmEd) to demo it!

Answer (score 0):

display:inline-block should be the best solution, this will display clickable boxes in one line if there is space for them:

```
.clickable-box {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Also add text-align:center to parent div in order for clickable boxes to be centered

```
.container-inner {
   width: 90%;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it. I modified the CSS a bit to add some borders to see what the boxes look like. You could certainly remove those borders.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bhok1z34/)

```
.container-main {
 width: 100%;
}
.container-inner {
    width: 90%;
    border:3px solid #454;
    text-align:center;
}
.clickable-box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline-block;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use float rules because they can push down the boxes that do not fit. For instance, float:left will get you at least two boxes on a 1096px. **`display:inline`** might have issues on browser rendering.

```
.container-main {
 width: 100%;
}
.container-inner {
 width: 90%;
}
.clickable-box {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 float:left; // right there. 
}
```

Comment: but float will leave an empty space if theres not enough room, and it won't be centered